# How to check an array is subset of another array of arrays in js?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays, where `arr1` is a subset of `arr2`, but I am unable to check  this using Javascript.

```
arr1 = [1,2]; //array1
arr2 = [[1,2],[2,3],[1,3],[1,4]]; //array2
```

I tried achieving this by using `arr2.includes(arr1)` which always returns `false`.

```
let arr1 = [1,2];
let arr2 = [[1,2],[2,3],[1,3],[1,4]];

console.log(arr2.includes(arr1)); //getting false
```

I expect the output to be `true`, but the actual output is `false`.
Can anyone help me solve this problem and direct me whether this is the right approach to solve this problem or not?

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.stringify` and compare with the individual arrays in arr2

```js
var arr1 = [1,2]; 
var arr2 = [[1,2],[2,3],[1,3],[1,4]];
arr2.forEach(function(e){
JSON.stringify(e)==JSON.stringify(arr1)?console.log(true):false})
```